# Can I expect this call to be inlined?

Tags: c++, g++

```
A * a = new B();
a->foo();
```

Suppose B derives A and foo() is a virtual function. This example is quite frequent, the problem is that in some places it is said that compiler won't attempt to inline this, where in other places the exact opposite is stated.

I personally do not see a reason why this call could not be inlined, because it is quite easy to tell in compile time which function is getting called.

Edit 1:
I am aware of the "general case", and am also aware that the compiler takes many factors to decide whether to inline or not. The question would be probably better formed if I asked if the compiler **might** inline this **particular** call.

The reason I am asking this is this particular quote from  [this C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/inline-virtuals.html) which says:

> When the object is referenced via a pointer or a reference, a call to a virtual function cannot be inlined, since the call must be resolved dynamically.

Comment: If "this example is quite frequent" I would guess the code is misusing subtype polymorphism.

Comment: I meant it is quite frequent on the internet when someone is explaining inlining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, g++ apparently inlines at least some trivial cases of virtual calls correctly; this is similar to your case, just a bit tweaked to get more readable assembler :)

```
void test(int);

class A { public: virtual int Bop() { return 1; } };

class B : public A { virtual int Bop() { return 4711; } };

int main() {
  A* a = new B();
  test(a->Bop());
}

$ g++ -O99 -S -c test.cpp

$ less test.s
...
main:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $8, %edi
    call    _Znwm
    movl    $4711, %edi            // hard coded 4711
    movq    $_ZTV1B+16, (%rax)
    call    _Z4testi               // calls test()
...
```

Comment: I guess you have answered what I asked for :) Might I ask what you think about the quote from the C++ FAQ that is in the question? Because to me it doesn't seem correct after this experiment. (The quote is the reason I asked the question)

Comment: @HonzaBrabec In general it's correct, but if the compiler can trivially deduce the type like this I can't see any reason to _forbid_ inlining. This kind of code seldom shows up other than in contrived examples though.

Comment: @HonzaBrabec: "_to me it doesn't seem correct after this experiment_" - the experiment is the result of one such situation, while it's not guarenteed that it'll be inlined by the standard like Andy Prowl says; so it isn't right to conclude based on one sample experiment, with just one compiler. This is the reason C++ FAQ says what it says.

Answer (score 4):

If the compiler can somehow deduce that the object pointed by `a` is an instance of `B` (i.e. if the code is trivial, like in your example), then it *could* devirtualize the call - although it is not required to do so.

But the point is that, in general, the call is resolved **at run-time**, because you don't know (and neither does the compiler!) what is the dynamic type of the object pointed to by `a`.

In other words, if the compiler does not know what is the dynamic type of `*a`, and consequently does not know which `foo()` function should be called until run-time, it is impossible to devirtualize the call and inline it at compile-time.

Comment: This is not answering the question. In the OP's example snippet, the compiler *can* derive the type of `*a` trivially.

Comment: Maybe we interpret the question differently, but I read it as *will G++ actually inline this call* (or at least devirtualize it) at some optimization setting, not *is it allowed to*.

Comment: @larsmans: Which version of gcc? The point is that yes, to some degree one could expect that the compiler will inline that call - it is feasible. But if the question is "will this call ever, ever be inlined by all versions of gcc (or any compiler)?" then the answer is "you cannot tell", because the compiler is not required to do that.

Comment: @larsmans you understand me perfectly :) I am aware of the "in general case" I was just wondering if it is ok to expect from the compiler to perform this kind of optimization

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a translation unit like this:

**compute.cpp:**

```
#include "A.h"

int compute(A * p)
{
    return p->get_some_int() * 10;
}
```

How do you think that virtual function call could possibly be devirtualized? Here's a usage example:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

int compute(A *);

int main()
{
    A * p = rand() % 2 == 0 ? new B : new C;
    return compute(x);
}
```

Comment: I don't think he means _all_ uses, just in the specific case he mentions where the value is allocated the line before the use.

Comment: Couldn't a clever compiler inline some calls to virtual functions ? I mean, in his example, it may appear pretty well at compile time which function needs to be called..

Comment: @JBL: But `main.cpp` and `compute.cpp` are *compiled separately and independently*... `main` doesn't know how `compute` is defined, and `compute` doesn't know how it's called.

Comment: @KerrekSB so what? `main` is not the compiler, and neither is `compute`. Those are not the entities that need such knowledge. When you ask for a complete program, your implementation gets to know the complete program.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: OK, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't **expect** the compiler to inline it. That's up to the compiler and the picked optimisation levels. Given that the implementation for B::foo is visible and that you have done nothing between the assignment and the call, then, yes, visual inspection suggests there is enough information available for the compiler to make that optimisation.

But it doesn't have to.

And in a lot of other situations, it won't have sufficient information.

Comment: I have edited the question. I realised the word "expect" was ill-chosen